# How to have Apps Script Web App work without disabling Site Isolation in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-apps-script, iframe, web-applications

I have a published Web App developed with Apps Script. This app has an input field to upload a file. It takes about 10s until the file is completely uploaded. If I click on any other existing input field on the page while the file is uploading, the page moves out of screen and becomes visible only part of it or sometimes I get a blank screen (it depends of which input field was clicked). The page comes back to normal only when the file is uploaded completely. 
I have figured out that if I disable Site Isolation in Chrome (chrome://flags/#site-isolation-trial-opt-out) then page is displayed correctly. Also it is working fine with Internet Explorer.

Here are some screenshots.

Select a file and click button to upload[image]

While the file is uploading[image]

How the page is displayed after any of input fields was clicked[image]

Any help would be appreciated.